# I've been got this error on this MySQL query?

Tags: php

I have receive my value from html form..the value received perfectly..but the problem of with BIND_PARAM() with prepared statement?can i am using php 7.0.1 version

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(empty(($_POST['fname'])) && empty(($_POST['lname'])) && empty(($_POST['dg'])) )
    {
        header("Location:view.html/form.html");
    }
    else
    {
        $f_name=addslashes($_POST['fname']);
        $l_name=addslashes($_POST['lname']);
        $post=addslashes($_POST['dg']);
    }

//----------------connection to database using Pdo------------------
    $hostname="localhost";
    $uname="root";
    $password="";
    $database_name="test";
    $conn= new mysqli($hostname,$uname,$password) or die("cannot connect to database Mysql");
    $stm=$conn->prepare("insert into s_detail(F_Name,L_Name,Designation) values(?,?,?)");
    $stm->bind_param("sss",$f_name,$l_name,$post);
    //set parameter and execute
    $f_name=addslashes($_POST['fname']);
        $l_name=addslashes($_POST['lname']);
        $post=addslashes($_POST['dg']);
    if($stm->execute())
    {
        $stm->close();
        echo "data is inserted successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "failed to insert";
    }
}
else
{
  echo "Don't be oversmart with me";
}
?>
```

The error is...

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp_7\htdocs\oops in php\oops.php:24 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp_7\htdocs\oops in php\oops.php on line 24
```

Plz help .....

Answer (score 0):

You need to also add the database parameter. That's missing

```
$conn= new mysqli($hostname,$uname,$password,$database_name);
```

As a habit, always check to see if you are successfully connected to the intended database

```
if($conn ==== false) {
die('error on connecting to database '.$conn->connect_error);
}
```